# How do I get started capturing and saving Project Tango point cloud data as a mesh?

Tags: google-project-tango

I am in a similar situation as caspertm was when asking this question: [How do I export Point Cloud Data (Project Tango)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070136/how-do-i-export-point-cloud-data-project-tango)

I apologize that I cannot comment on other questions yet or I would have just done so on that question.  I too was looking for the functionality the mapper app provided (specifically the capturing and saving of 3d environments) and have found through searching and reading that question that it is not available for the tablet.  The answer provided to caspertm's question was to use the point cloud data sample code as a starting point and modify it to log the data to a file.

I am wondering if anyone would be willing to go into more detail about what needs to be modified to the point cloud sample (I am using the Java version) to save that data and retrieve it later on my computer so I can manipulate it in a program like blender or unity.

I am very new to the android developing process.  I can read the sample point cloud java code and get a very basic understanding of what is going on, but I definitely have a lot of learning to do.  I realize I am asking for a lot of help and don't expect any one person (or even several) to paint me the entire picture, but tips on things like: whether this data should be saved internally or externally, which java file requires the saving code, how to format the file to be readable in other 3d programs and how to see more than just the current snapshot of the point cloud would be greatly appreciated.  If anyone could point me in the right direction of how to get the actual environment colors projected onto the cloud data, that would be amazing too, but any help or links for any of these requests would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Comment: btw, have you tried the 3d reconstruction API? Tango has java example for it too: https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/tree/master/java_mesh_builder_example

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses only computational geometry aspects - issues involved in getting the point cloud, phoning home with it, stuffing it in a file, etc are considered 'self evident' in order to more quickly go play with the math  :-)

Nice shallow pretty answer - if you're scanning something where the point cloud represents an object with *fair* curvy or straight surface then the suggestions here will help -- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7028/wrapping-a-mesh-around-point-cloud-with-cavities  Please note that 'fair' is a loaded word.

The more detailed answer isn't pretty - and reality will have a way of handing you point clouds that make the preceding algorithms very irritated.  If you are looking to take a random cloud of points (yes, I know its a meaningful cloud of points to you, but mathematicians make much of these details) and reconstruct a geometry from it, i.e. define the **topology** that relates those points in a meaningful way,  you're talking about a very nasty problem.  Check the internet for discussions of Delaunay Triangulation and Voronoi diagrams, which are the more traditional approaches to solving this issue.  Sort of.  Its pretty straightforward if you were scanning a model of a volcano.  Assuming Tango could see it (I think probably not), scanning the Calder mobile at JFK would give pretty much anyone a drinking problem.  The algorithms themselves assume a planar basis, and do not react well to fiddling with that assumption.  Explaining this requires talking about manifolds, and reading between the lines in your question, I'm assuming you'd rather not have me go any further.

You should be able to find some open source implementations -  if it builds and passes all of its unit tests, then you should be OK using it as a black box.  If you have to reach inside, be careful.  Those things bite  :-)

Comment: What's your opinion about pcl_surface http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__surface.html ? Do you think it can be used for mesh reconstruction for Tango point cloud? That point cloud certainly won't be as closed as a 3D scan of a bunny.

Comment: Looks interesting - can't hurt to try - let us know what you find - point clouds will occupy a lot of attention on this topic, i think :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I can partially answer the question:
In terms of saving the points, it should be fairly simple, you could have a file open and keep writing the points data into the file when the callback is being called. However, as Project Tango Developer website mentioned, the data provided from API is just the points, not mesh. That means after getting the points you will need to figure out your own way to construct indices.