# Google - Project Tango - Point Cloud Extraction - Skeletal Tracking

Tags: google-project-tango

Has anyone had any luck extracting point cloud data into the Tango File system? Also looking for anyone who's had luck with skeletal tracking via point cloud data.

Any tips or suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding extracting the point cloud data to the file system, please take a look of this post: [How do I export Point Cloud Data (Project Tango)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070136/how-do-i-export-point-cloud-data-project-tango)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jason. Point Cloud extraction was a bit more tricky on the Java side of things, but it's working!

We're noticing some pretty slow performance when exporting the point cloud data in real time. Would love to hear tips on improving the performance of the I/O!

Still no word on existing skeletal tracking engines. Is there a java based NUI out there anywhere?

Comment: what is the bottom neck of I/O you are referring to? i.e writing to a file? Could you buffer everything up and write it at one time. Note that the point cloud actually updates at 3hz at the moment, there is no method to make that faster..