# Project Tango export scan file with scale

Tags: export, google-project-tango, .obj

As I see it, one can use the constructor app to create scans and also export those in two different file formats, one being `.srb` and one being `.obj`. 
The former is mostly unreadable though:

```
tango
version 1.0
element vertex 73380
element normal 73380
element color 73380
element face 127292
end_header
ëQˆ¿‰5–¿)\Ï¾ëQˆ¿®—¿wqÍ¾œ†¿®—¿)\Ï¾<.ï¾q=º¿HáZ¿{î¾¢»¿HáZ¿{î¾q=º¿ÜJ[¿{î¾ff¶¿‘4]¿ëmö¾ff¶¿HáZ¿xï¾…ëÁ¿43S¿{î¾_ÛÃ¿43S¿{î¾…ëÁ¿¤-V¿{î¾{¾¿Ë‘W¿ª¿ð¾{¾¿43S¿%õ¾q=º¿43S¿ú‹ý¾ff¶¿43S¿£pý¾…¶¿43S¿£pý¾ff¶¿¹
T¿Soï¾…ëÁ¿…K¿{î¾ÿÄ¿…K¿pñ¾{¾¿…K¿–õ¾q=º¿…K¿Êâþ¾ff¶¿…K¿£pý¾B¯·¿…K¿ZGï¾…ëÁ¿×C¿{î¾áÃ¿×C¿Èò¾{¾¿×C¿¹%ö¾q=º¿×C¿´Mþ¾ff¶¿×C¿£pý¾:·¿×C¿ï¾…ëÁ¿ö(<¿{î¾¼Â¿ö(<¿cò¾{¾¿ö(<¿[ó¾q=º¿ö(<¿Ýþ¾ff¶¿ö(<¿£pý¾/}·¿ö(<¿{î¾ff¶¿‹üA¿{î¾ †·¿ö(<¿8ƒó¾ff¶¿ö(<¿{î¾…ëÁ¿—g9¿Õ¨ñ¾{¾¿âz4¿{î¾h|À¿âz4¿"Oó¾q=º¿âz4¿ïþ¾ff¶¿âz4¿£pý¾Ã%·¿âz4¿{î¾‘æ¸¿âz4¿ \ú¾ff¶¿âz4¿ið¾{¾¿ÍÌ,¿{î¾_¿¿ÍÌ,¿Êñ¾q=º¿ÍÌ,¿Üþ¾ff¶¿ÍÌ,¿£pý¾àç¶¿ÍÌ,¿{î¾=Š¹¿ÍÌ,¿÷û¾ff¶¿ÍÌ,¿²ÿî¾{¾¿¹%¿{î¾:þ¾¿¹%¿5öð¾q=º¿¹%¿ŸXþ¾ff¶¿¹%¿£pý¾u?·¿¹%¿{î¾ï¹¿¹%¿ðöû¾ff¶¿¹%¿{î¾{¾¿©œ!¿ºÖð¾q=º¿¤p¿{î¾Âd¼¿¤p¿RÌý¾ff¶¿¤p¿£pý¾Æ¼¶¿¤p¿{î¾ú¹¿¤p¿bõü¾ff¶¿¤p¿qcî¾{¾¿Â¿{î¾º]¾¿Â¿{î¾{¾¿wv¿{î¾q=º¿°¿{î¾»½¿Â¿"¹ý¾ff¶¿Â¿£pý¾áª¶¿Â¿9ý¾ff¶¿Â¿{î¾{¾¿ât¿£pý¾ff¶¿s¿·v¿q=j¿×£€?gf¿Åsj¿×£€?gf¿R6o¿˜™y?™¿q=j¿˜™y?¸…¿…ëq¿˜™y?ªW¿…ëq¿×£€?¾X    ¿]b¿˜™y?†¯¿]b¿×£€?gN
```

At the same time, the `.obj` file is readable but to my knowledge does not include a scale ([which it only could in form of a comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)). An example looks like this:

```
#tango v 73380 f 127292
v -1.0649999 -1.1735088 -0.405 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
v -1.0649999 -1.185 -0.4012563 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
v -1.0516545 -1.185 -0.405 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
v -0.46714962 -1.455 -0.855 0.29803923 0.30980393 0.31764707 1.0
v -0.465 -1.4619029 -0.855 0.29803923 0.30980393 0.31764707 1.0
v -0.465 -1.455 -0.856611 0.29803923 0.30980393 0.31764707 1.0
v -0.465 -1.425 -0.86408335 0.24313726 0.25882354 0.27450982 1.0
v -0.48130736 -1.425 -0.855 0.3137255 0.32156864 0.32941177 1.0
v -0.46771282 -1.515 -0.82500005 0.3019608 0.31764707 0.33333334 1.0
v -0.465 -1.5301322 -0.82500005 0.3137255 0.32156864 0.3372549 1.0
v -0.465 -1.515 -0.8366339 0.3019608 0.31764707 0.33333334 1.0
v -0.465 -1.485 -0.8420684 0.29803923 0.30980393 0.32156864 1.0
v -0.47021228 -1.485 -0.82500005 0.3019608 0.3137255 0.32156864 1.0
[...]
```

My goal is to have the data displayed in these files *and* the scale so that for example I can get information about the size of my scan etc. Does anyone know how to include the scale in the `.obj` file or how to read the `.srb` file?

(I've already had a look at [How do I export Point Cloud Data Project Tango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070136/how-do-i-export-point-cloud-data-project-tango), but did not quite see a clear solution. I also found two apps from [Chucknology](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Chucknology), but they don't seem to work on my tango device (at least I can't access the expored ADF from my computer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting Feedback from the Tango Support, I'm happy to share that the scale is not lost, but preserved even when exporting to the `.obj` file format: It's simply in meters (i.e. 1.041235 would be roughly 104 cm)