# Project Tango: vrmesh file format?

Tags: intel, augmented-reality, google-project-tango, 360-virtual-reality

The [Project Tango Constructor](https://developers.google.com/ar) is able to save objects in the .obj file format. Is it possible to also have it save objects in the .vrmesh file format? Or is there another program available that would allow me to render and save real-world objects using the Intel RealSense 3D camera as .vrmesh files?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, using the tango constructor app, you can only save in .srb format but you can export your mesh later to .obj and .ply

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Are there programs out there that will allow me to save an object rendering as a point cloud?

Comment: well, why would you want to do that instead of saving the actual point cloud?

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding - I'm trying to see what the point clouds look like on my computer. How do I actually save the point cloud is what I'm asking.

Comment: Maybe this c an help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070136/how-do-i-export-point-cloud-data-project-tango/30563876#30563876