# Import and Export of point cloud - TangoPointCloudData

Tags: google-project-tango, tango

What I'm trying to achieve is the following, I have 2 Android apps(I'm only using Java API, no Unity) and I would like to capture on 1 app a Point Cloud and send it to the other App.

I'm doing the last part correct, but I do not know how to load the point cloud in the other app. Part of the problem is that TangoPointCloudData is constructed from objects that are not part of Android SDK and adding them means adding a JNI  libraries. Of Course simple serialization won't work here.

Seems like a huge overhead for that end.

If there isn't a way to achieve it easily on the **Java API**, is there a way to achieve it on the **Unity API**?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I export Point Cloud Data (Project Tango)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070136/how-do-i-export-point-cloud-data-project-tango)

Comment: @jason in the link you provided the person refers to a third part app - 'Tango Mapper'. My question is how(if it possible) I'm doing it using Tango SDK from code. By the way, are you from the Tango team at Google? If so I think that we've met at Bespoke - Westfield last January at Tango workshop

Comment: I am from Tango team :). About the question, there's not a out of box function to directly export raw point cloud into a file. The best way to do it is to modify the point cloud sample code, and let it output point cloud to a file