# How do I export Point Cloud Data (Project Tango) in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

As show in the topic, how do I export Point Cloud Data in apk created by Unity3D? And how can I use these data to creat 3D mesh or model in Unity3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a 3D mesh or model with Tango in Unity3D**

There is an example scene in the Unity Tango SDK that enables you to acquire and export a colored mesh directly in the apk app. Look at Assets\TangoSDK\Examples\Scenes\ExperimentalMeshBuilderWithColor.unity.

**Export Point Cloud Data in apk**

I don't think there is a function in the SDK that does that directly, but have a look to the following script : Assets\TangoSDK\Examples\Common\Scripts\TangoDynamicMesh.cs and more precisely the function `public void ExportMeshToObj(string filepath)` that exports a TangoDynamicMesh to an OBJ file format.

You could create a similar script that gets values from TangoPointCloud.m_mesh instead of a TangoDynamicMesh to export your pointcloud as an OBJ file.

Have also a look at this question: [How do I export Point Cloud Data (Project Tango)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27070136/7342703)

**Create a mesh from 3D points in Unity**

Creating a mesh from 3D points is not that easy and there is no straightforward way to do it in Unity. From an exported OBJ point cloud, you can use external tools like the [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/) or [Meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get point cloud data folowing this [example](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-howto-depth). After setting up everything as in guide, you can easily get coordinates of all points:

```c#
private Vector3[] GetPointCloudData()
{
    TangoPointCloud pointCloud = FindObjectOfType<TangoPointCloud>();
    return pointCloud.m_points;
}
```

However, with this you are getting only points that are currently visible on your device screen.

Once you send them to server, create gameobject containing Mesh and draw points:

```c#
public void CreateMesh(Vector3[] points)
{
    Util.Debug("Drawing...");
    mesh.Clear();

    int[] indecies = new int[points.Length];
    Color[] colors = new Color[points.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; ++i)
    {
        indecies[i] = i;
        colors[i] = Color.green;
    }

    mesh.vertices = points;
    mesh.colors = colors;
    mesh.SetIndices(indecies, MeshTopology.Points, 0);

}
```

Notice that colors are hardcoded, I didn't manage to get them from pointcloud data.

For extracting mesh you can follow this [example](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-howto-mesh-color) .